# Showing $A_5$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

For $H$ is a normal subgroup of $A_5$.

I know that the order of |aH| must divide both |$A_5$/H| and |a|. (Not entirely sure why it divides |a|, but that might be something to explain). From this we have to conclude that if |a| is relatively prime to all divisors of |A_5/H| then $a\in H$.

Is this just obvious once I explained why |aH| divides those things?

Also I have finally shown what the normal subgroups of $A_5$. But what sorts of homomorphic images of $A_5$ are possible?

Comment: What do you mean by $aH$ ?

Comment: the cosets of H

Comment: Then the cardinality of $aH$ is the same as the cardinality of $H$ and in general this does not divide the order of $a$. Also, I cannot see why this divides $|A_5/H|$.

Comment: the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group, which is why |aH| divides |$A_5/H$. Is there an example where it doesnt divide the order of A?

Comment: Yes it is true that $|H|$ divides $|A_5|$ but this does not guarantee that it divides also $|A_5/H|=\frac{|A_5|}{|H|}$. For example consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ and the subgroup $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times {0}$. Then $|H|=2$ and this does not divide $|G/H|=3$. Also, taking $a=0$, you can see that this does not divide $|a|=1$ as well.

Comment: I mean H is normal, which is why it works to begin with in the first place. So your not using the assumption that is needed for cosets in the first place

Comment: The $H$ in my example is normal as well, since $G$ is abelian and every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. Also, if in your case you consider $H=A_5$ then this is normal, but $|A_5|$ does not divide $|A_5/A_5|=1$. But if you are interested I am writing a proof of the simplicity in an answer.

Comment: yes I am interested, but the order of A_5 does divide the order of A_5 because its the same number.

Comment: Yes, but it does not divide the order of $A_5/H$.

Comment: Okay I think I see the confusion here. I am talking about the set $aH$ and its order of how it divides $|A_5/H|$ and the order of $|a|$. Not the subgroup H itself

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I have some problems with the chat. However, the coset $aH$ has the same order of $H$ so that $|aH|=|H|$. Then, what do you mean by |A_5/H| and the order of |a|? If you mean the cardinality of $A_5/H$ and the order of the element $a$, then taking $H=A_5$ and $a=id$ gives a counterexample. Indeed, if $|a|=1$,$|H|=60$ and $|A_5/H|=1$. Anyway if you want a proof there is a nicely explained one here:people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/A5.pdf

Comment: by |$A_5/H$| I mean the number of cosets and order of |a|=m as $a^m=e$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean, so that the counterexample holds.

Comment: $A_5$ is not a coset of H. but can we answer the original question. because everywhere I have seen is that the order of a coset divides both the order of the quotient group and the order of an element $a$ for $aH$.

Comment: If you want a proof that $A_5$ is simple then you can look at it here: people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/A5.pdf. However I think that you should check again your sources, because what you have seen is not true: $A_5$ is actually a coset of $H$, since $H=A_5$ and $A_5=eA_5$.

Comment: what if it was the factor group $A_5/H$. Is that the same thing as the quotient group?

Comment: Yes, usually by $A_5/H$ you mean the set of all cosets of $H$, and if $H$ is normal you can give this the structure of a group and call it the quotient group (or also the factor group I guess, even if I never heard that name).